# PasswordDigest authentication fails in JAX-WS client running in WebLogic

Tags: java, jax-ws, soap-client, weblogic12c

I'm trying to implement a JAX-WS web service client that uses PasswordDigest authentication.

This is my web service client:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.xml.ws.Binding;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature;

@Stateless
public class JaxWsService {

    /**
     * We cache the web service client, but on a thread local variable to avoid any potential multi-threading
     * issues.
     */
    private ThreadLocal<MyService> threadLocalClient = new ThreadLocal<MyService>();

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:9999/mockMyService?WSDL")
    private MyServiceInterface service;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
      AddressingFeature feature = new AddressingFeature(true, false);
      MyService proxy = service.getMyService(feature);

      List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
      //Add a handler to the handler chain
      handlerChain.add( new PasswordDigestHeaderHandler() );
      Binding binding = ( ( BindingProvider )proxy ).getBinding();
      binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);

      threadLocalClient.set(proxy);
    }

    public Response doSomething(String guid) {
      MyService client = threadLocalClient.get();
      return client.doSomething(guid);
  }
}
```

This is my *SOAPHandler*:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

import ca.ns.gov.sns.rmv.util.PropertyUtil;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class PasswordDigestHeaderHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

  private static final String USERNAME = "username";
  private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
  private static DateFormat headerDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
  private static final String ENCODING_UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
  private static final String wssePrefix = "wsse";
  private static final String wsseURI = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
  private static final String wsuPrefix = "wsu";
  private static final String wsuURI = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"; 

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            try {

                // Nonce
                SecureRandom rand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
                rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
                byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[16];
                rand.nextBytes(nonceBytes);

                // Created date
                headerDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                String createdDate = headerDateFormat.format(now.getTime());
                byte[] createdDateBytes = createdDate.getBytes(ENCODING_UTF_8);

                // Password
                byte[] passwordBytes = PASSWORD.getBytes(ENCODING_UTF_8);

                // SHA-1 hash the bunch of it.
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                baos.write(nonceBytes);
                baos.write(createdDateBytes);
                baos.write(passwordBytes);
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                byte[] digestedPassword = md.digest(baos.toByteArray());

                // Encode the password and nonce                   
                String passwordB64 = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(digestedPassword);
                String nonceB64 = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(nonceBytes);

                now.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1000);
                String expiresTimestamp = headerDateFormat.format(now.getTime());

                SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();

                // Security
                SOAPElement securityE = factory.createElement("Security", wssePrefix, wsseURI);
                securityE.addNamespaceDeclaration(wssePrefix, wsseURI);
                securityE.addNamespaceDeclaration(wsuPrefix, wsuURI);
                securityE.addAttribute(new QName("mustUnderstand"), "1"); 

                // Security/Timestamp
                SOAPElement timestampE = factory.createElement("Timestamp", wsuPrefix, wsuURI);
                timestampE.setAttributeNS(wsuURI, "wsu:Id", "TS-" + generateRandomString());

                SOAPElement createdE = factory.createElement("Created", wsuPrefix, wsuURI);
                createdE.addTextNode(createdDate);
                timestampE.addChildElement(createdE);

                SOAPElement expiresE = factory.createElement("Expires", wsuPrefix, wsuURI);
                expiresE.addTextNode(expiresTimestamp);
                timestampE.addChildElement(expiresE);

                // Security/UsernameToken
                SOAPElement usernameTokenE = factory.createElement("UsernameToken", wssePrefix, wsseURI);
                usernameTokenE.setAttributeNS(wsuURI, "wsu:Id", "UsernameToken-" + generateRandomString());

                SOAPElement userE = factory.createElement("Username", wssePrefix, wsseURI);
                userE.addTextNode(USERNAME);

                SOAPElement pwdE = factory.createElement("Password", wssePrefix, wsseURI);
                pwdE.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest");
                pwdE.addTextNode(passwordB64);

                SOAPElement nonceE = factory.createElement("Nonce", wssePrefix, wsseURI);
                nonceE.setAttribute("EncodingType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary");
                nonceE.addTextNode(nonceB64);

                usernameTokenE.addChildElement(userE);
                usernameTokenE.addChildElement(pwdE);
                usernameTokenE.addChildElement(nonceE);
                usernameTokenE.addChildElement(createdE);

                securityE.addChildElement(timestampE);
                securityE.addChildElement(usernameTokenE);

                SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();

                if (header == null){
                    header = envelope.addHeader();
                }

                header.addChildElement(securityE);

                context.getMessage().saveChanges();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return outboundProperty;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        QName securityHeader = new QName(wsseURI, "Security", wssePrefix); 
        HashSet<QName> headers = new HashSet<QName>(); 
        headers.add(securityHeader);         
        return headers; 
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {}

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a random string used in the Timestamp and UsernameToken elements.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private String generateRandomString() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
    }
```

... and these are my web service artifacts generate by ClientGenTask:

```
@WebServiceClient...
public class MyServiceInterface
    extends Service
{
```

...

```
@WebService...
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface MyService {
```

... and this is the web service's policy:

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="wss_username_token_over_ssl_service_policy_PasswordDigest">
   <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
      <wsp:Policy>
         <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <wsp:Policy>
               <sp:Basic128/>
            </wsp:Policy>
         </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
         <sp:TransportToken>
            <wsp:Policy>
               <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false">
                  <wsp:Policy/>
               </sp:HttpsToken>
            </wsp:Policy>
         </sp:TransportToken>
         <sp:Layout>
            <wsp:Policy>
               <sp:Lax/>
            </wsp:Policy>
         </sp:Layout>
         <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
      </wsp:Policy>
   </sp:TransportBinding>
   <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
      <wsp:Policy>
         <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
            <wsp:Policy>
               <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
            </wsp:Policy>
         </sp:UsernameToken>
      </wsp:Policy>
   </sp:SupportingTokens>
</wsp:Policy>
```

The bulk of the code is taken from a standalone application that I wrote as a proof of concept, which was working fine. I was able to hit the web service and get the expected response.

But when I migrated the code to run inside Weblogic 12.1.3, I started getting this error:

> Caused By: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Unable to add security token for identity, token uri =http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken

Is there some setup that needs to be done through the WebLogic console in order to enable *PasswordDigest* from the client side, or am I missing something in the code?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Caused By: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Unable to add security token for identity, token uri =http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:290)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy367.retrieveDocumentRequest(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy365.retrieveDocumentRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.myclient.project.services.ods.myservice.MyServiceSOAJaxWsService.retrieveDocument(MyServiceSOAJaxWsService.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:100)
    at com.myclient.project.audit.AuditInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AuditInterceptor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:109)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy358.retrieveDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.myclient.project.services.ods.myservice.MyServiceSOAJaxWsService_elmy9k_myserviceServiceImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33)
    at com.myclient.project.services.ods.myservice.MyServiceSOAJaxWsService_elmy9k_myserviceServiceImpl.retrieveDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.myclient.project.services.ods.MyServiceBean.retrieveDocument(MyServiceBean.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:100)
    at com.myclient.project.audit.AuditInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AuditInterceptor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:109)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy353.retrieveDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.myclient.project.services.ods.MyService_tev81c_MyServiceImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at com.myclient.project.services.ods.MyService_tev81c_MyServiceImpl.retrieveDocument(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy151.retrieveDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.myclient.project.web.ods.ODSRenderAttachment.init(ODSRenderAttachment.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:170)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1785)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1781)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:452)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at com.myclient.project.util.faces.CustomViewHandler.renderView(CustomViewHandler.java:63)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:604)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at com.myclient.project.util.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:54)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at com.myclient.project.util.PersistenceFilter.doFilter(PersistenceFilter.java:86)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at com.myclient.project.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:83)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at com.myclient.project.util.ClientTransactionConversationFilter.doFilter(ClientTransactionConversationFilter.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Strangely, if I take the XML that's generated/output by the *PasswordDigestHeaderHandler* (below) and paste it into SoapUI, the request works. This seems to hint at some missing WebLogic configuration.

```
<S:Envelope
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header>
        <wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-6b8a287b7bf641f19b6841d555e9f380">
                <wsu:Created>2018-11-13T18:11:53.541Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2018-11-13T18:28:33.541Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-183099de358f4f0685eb34783a8b1c5c">
                <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">42Nl15QHYJymbpxFDFC5kccoWuk=</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">9NTLR/h+GQQwRd1fQRxnqg==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created
                    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2018-11-13T18:11:53.541Z
                </wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <RetrieveDocumentRequest
            xmlns="http://mycompany.com/MyService">
            ...
        </RetrieveDocumentRequest>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Check the server side logs, they might give more insight. Also what's the WS-Policy look like for the WebLogic server?

Comment: I've updated the question with the policy and the full stack trace. Unfortunately I don't have access to the server logs for the service I am trying to invoke.

Comment: The stack trace only indicates that the server couldn't add a security token based on what it got. `Client received SOAP Fault from server: Unable to add security token for identity, token uri =http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken`

Comment: I was wondering if there were namespace issues. But it looks and sounds like that's fine especially if you say the generated SOAP works when you send it via SoapUI. It does sound like a client environment issue then, I'm just trying to think what in the client environment would stop the server from being able to add the token.

Comment: I've edited my answer, try it with the updates. Wondering if somehow the client not trusting the server is causing the issue? If not this then mess around more with the client environment.

Comment: With the modifications, it again results in:  Caused By: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Timestamp validation failed.

Comment: Additionally have a look at [this example from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WSSOV/ws-security-message.htm#CDEHFHFC) and maybe this [other thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1361407)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

1. Download the WSDL file that describes your service and modify it by commenting out line that defines the *wsp:PolicyReference:*.

[image]

2. Place it in a folder which will be included in your jar/war/ear file (eg. META-INF/wsdl).
3. In your web service client, change your @WebServiceRef injection to reference this local/bundled version of the WSDL:

   ```
   @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/MyService.wsdl")
   private MyServiceInterface service;
   ```
4. Modify your client initialization code to something like the following:

   ```
   AddressingFeature feature = new AddressingFeature(true, false);
   MyService proxy = service.getMyService(feature);
   BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) proxy;

   List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
   //Add a handler to the handler chain
   handlerChain.add( new PasswordDigestHeaderHandler() );
   Binding binding = bindingProvider.getBinding();
   binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);

   // Add these two lines, to point to the remote service
   Map<String, Object> context = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
   context.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, REMOTE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT);

   threadLocalClient.set(proxy);
   ```

... where REMOTE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT is the URL to the remote web service that you are hitting.

That should do it. You shouldn't have to modify your PasswordDigestHeaderHandler implementation.

I spent a considerable amount of time on exactly this same issue, but this thread set me down the right path: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2485783.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `init()` method, you may need to add a `WebLogic` credential provider:

```
private void init() {
    AddressingFeature feature = new AddressingFeature(true, false);
    MyService proxy = service.getMyService(feature);

    List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<>();
    // Add a handler to the handler chain
    handlerChain.add(new PasswordDigestHeaderHandler());

    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) proxy;
    Binding binding = bindingProvider.getBinding();
    binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);

    // weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.provider.CredentialProvider
    // weblogic.wsee.security.unt.ClientUNTCredentialProvider
    List<CredentialProvider> credProviders = new ArrayList<>();
    credProviders.add(new ClientUNTCredentialProvider(USERNAME.getBytes(), PASSWORD.getBytes()));

    Map<String, Object> context = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
    // weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WSSecurityContext
    context.put(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST, credProviders);
    // weblogic.security.SSL.TrustManager
    context.put(
        WSSecurityContext.TRUST_MANAGER,
        new TrustManager() {
            public boolean certificateCallback(X509Certificate[] chain, int validateErr) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    );

    threadLocalClient.set(proxy);
}
```

Comment: I tried that approach and I get the following error:  com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Timestamp validation failed. I also have to comment out the handler chain code, otherwise I end up with two UsernameToken and two Timestamp elements. Also this approach does not encrypt the password, it creates a PasswordText password.

Comment: Hmm, which approach gets further, does Timestamp validation or adding a Security Token come later in the server's processing? Probably the latter. Do you have something printing out your client request so you/we can check it? If logs aren't doing that for you then you can use `<SOAPMessage>.writeTo(OutputStream)`

Comment: I added the generated XML and an additional comment to the original question.